What happens to the variables stored in the lifecycle state in FastAPI?
I have a FastAPI app with MongoDB connected via Motor. I open a MongoDB connection at the beginning of an app and close it at the end using lifespan:
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app):
    mongo_client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongo://")
    mongo_db = mongo_client["mydb"]
    yield {"db": mongo_db}
    mongo_client.close()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return request.state.db

Before the latest versions of Starlette this used to be saved inside app.state but now it is saved in request.state. The way I have to access the db variable from inside the Request object makes me think that the database client is being tagged along with every single request, and is potentially open to vulnerabilities from the client.
What exactly happens to the state variable? Does it really travel together with each request or is it safe to store my database client here?

Try fastapi.Depends. You can use it to create a session automatically for every request.

Yes. I am using it in the example 1. This is how official documentation do SQL sessions. However, in Mongo it is an overhead to open and close client for every single request. That is why I have to open and close the client in the lifespan context.

In my projects I use middleware to create a session for a database, like so:
# db_middleware.py

from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware, RequestResponseEndpoint
from starlette.responses import Response
from starlette.requests import Request
from fastapi import FastAPI
from db.session import Session


class DbMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, app: FastAPI) -> None:
        super().__init__(app)

    async def dispatch(
        self, request: Request, call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint
    ) -> Response:
        try:
            request.state.db = Session()
            response = await call_next(request)
        finally:
            if hasattr(request.state, "db") and request.state.db is not None:
                request.state.db.close()
        return response

# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
from middlewares.db_middleware import DbMiddleware


def create_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.add_middleware(DbMiddleware)
    return app


app = create_app()


In my experience, with this approach it is possible to control which database should be used at a particular point in time

Please, correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like you are opening and closing a database session for every request, because, as far as I understand, every single request passes through middleware. This seems like an overhead, because one shared session must be enough for all requests.. Moreover, it stores the db information in the request.state. My question is exactly that, actually: is it appropriate to safe a sensitive information like database client in the request.

@RavshanS.K. yes, you are correct that a database session is created and closed for each request. However, this is not an overhead, but rather a standard and recommended practice
The main basic reason to do this is to isolate the database operation on a per-request basis. It means that changes made by one request will not accidentally "leak" into another request
